# How to hide UITabBarController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to hide it with animation ?

Comment: I put a variation on the solutions proposed below here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031804/how-to-hide-tab-bar-programatically-and-then-expand-view-to-fit/15855340#15855340

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A UITabBar inherits from UIView, so you can hide it and animate it like you would with a standard UIView.

```
- (void) hideTheTabBarWithAnimation:(BOOL) withAnimation {
    if (NO == withAnimation) {
        [theTabBar setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];

        [theTabBar setAlpha:0.0];       

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I haven't tested it myself, I believe this would just hide the view but still keep its frame there (hence new views would be impeded by this hidden frame). A better way is to use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property on the *vc* that will be pushed

Comment: The best answer for me. I am really a very happy. So we have to manager other thing. You solved my problem in second. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 23):

You should use this code:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: It's leaving a black space for me in place of the tab bar... Not a good solution

Answer (score 6):

You can also hide it using the attributes inspector:

[image]

but not with an animation.

Comment: This is simple and perfect

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)hideTabBar
{   UITabBarController * tabbarcontroller= appDelegate.tabBarVC;
        if (tabbarcontroller.tabBar.isHidden) 
    {
        return;
    }
    tabbarcontroller.tabBar.hidden=YES;
    CGRect frm=tabbarcontroller.view.frame;
    frm.size.height += tabbarcontroller.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    tabbarcontroller.view.frame=frm;
}
-(void)showTabBar
{    UITabBarController * tabbarcontroller=appDelegate.tabBarVC;
    if (!tabbarcontroller.tabBar.isHidden)
    {
        return;
    }
    CGRect frm=tabbarcontroller.view.frame;
    frm.size.height -= tabbarcontroller.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    tabbarcontroller.view.frame=frm;
    tabbarcontroller.tabBar.hidden=NO;  
}
here appDelegate is = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
tabBarVc is UITabBarController *tabBarVC defined as property in app delegate
hope this helps
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution I use:
Call Methods When You Want to Hide Menu:

```
//Show Tab Bar
[self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
//If You Want to Hide/Show Navigation Bar Also
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:YES];

//Hide Tab Bar
[self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];  
//If You Want to Hide/Show Navigation Bar Also
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

Methods:

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width,            
      view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else
    {
      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y,        
      view.frame.size.width, 480)];
    }
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width,    
      view.frame.size.height)];

    }
    else
    {
      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y,  
      view.frame.size.width, 431)];
     }
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```