# Hide UITabBarController and make view fit

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to hide tab bar controller when click a button in view, and then show it again when clicking another button. I've checked the code in this link: [How to hide tab bar programatically and then expand view to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031804/how-to-hide-tab-bar-programatically-and-then-expand-view-to-fit/15855340#15855340) but unable to do it.

I need to hide the tab bar controller and expand a UITableView so that there is no empty space where the tab bar is.

Anyone has a solution for this? I'm using Xcode 8 with auto-layout enabled.

Comment: did you perform push operation on click of button ?

Comment: not push operation...just a normal function